# Find branch point and branch cut of $\log(z-(1+z^2)^{1/2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question was to find the branch point and branch cut of $\log(z-(1+z^2)^{1/2})$.
My approach was first to consider the square root function.
The branch point of the square root function exists where the value inside the square root is 0.

So, $1+z^2 = 0$ or $z = \pm i$
Now, consider the $\log$ function. Branch points of $\log$ function exist when the value inside log is zero.
$$z -(1+z^2)^{1/2} = 0$$
which turns out to be not possible for any value of $z$.

Next we check if $z=\infty$ is branch point or not.

For that we substitute $z = \frac{1}{t}$ and let $t \to 0$, so that $z \to \infty$.
$$\log\left(\frac{1}{t} - \left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)^{1/2}\right) = \log(1-(1+t^2)^{1/2}) - \log(t)$$

Clearly the function has branch point at $t = 0, \infty$.
So, $f(z)$ has branch point at $z = 0, \infty$.

So, in total I have four branch points, $z = 0, \pm i, \infty$.

My doubt is whether my calculated branch points are right and if I am doing the right mathematical method to calculate them. Also, how to proceed in finding the branch cut.

Edit: $z = 0$ is not a branch point of the given function.

Comment: You can’t necessarily say $\log(a/b)=\log(a)-\log(b)$ if you’re specifying a particular branch

Comment: 0 shouldnt be a branch point i don't think? It should just be $\pm i$ and infinity. As for the branch cuts you can draw any two lines extending from your two branch points out to infinity, and if you want a finite branch cut just make the branch cuts overlap and I think the arguments should match.